# How do I remove the gap between two bars when using Rectangle shape in recharts

Tags: reactjs, recharts

In following code I have added some sample objects in data variable that can be used to give widths to the bars. But this works in a way that each bar have the same width and the color is only applied to the "customWidth".

```
import {
  ResponsiveContainer,
  BarChart,
  Bar,
  Tooltip,
  XAxis,
  Rectangle,
} from "recharts";

const data = [{ customWidth: 300 }, { customWidth: 200 }, { customWidth: 50 }];

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <ResponsiveContainer width="100%" height={300}>
        <BarChart
          data={data}
          barCategoryGap={0} // Set gap between bars within the same category to 0
          barGap={0} // Set gap between bars from different categories to 0
        >
          <Tooltip />
          <XAxis />
          <Bar
            dataKey="customWidth"
            isAnimationActive={false}
            shape={(props) => <CustomBar {...props} width={props.width} />}
          />
        </BarChart>
      </ResponsiveContainer>
    </div>
  );
}

function CustomBar(props: any) {
  return <Rectangle {...props} width={props.customWidth} />;
}
```

[image: Output of above code]